# Create a countmedian function using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function CountMedians that counts the number of times the median value occurs in the x vector. This function should be called with the required parameter x as its
only parameter, and it should return a vector with two named components: Median, and Count.

Comment: Please show what you've already tried and then if you're getting any error in your approach after making the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.

```
CountMedians=function(x)c(Median=median(x),Count=sum(x==median(x)))
```

Thus with `x=c(1,2,3,3,4,5)`, `CountMedians(x)` returns:

```
> CountMedians(x)
Median  Count 
     3      2
```

Comment: Did you see @Jilber's edit to your post? It's probably easier to just put the names in the vector. Plus, it's probably not a good idea to have the function print the values. Just return them and the caller can print them if they like.